# Class inheritance is defined statically at compile-time, so it is not possible to change the implementations inherited from parent class at run-time?

Tags: python, class

I read recently that ***class inheritance is defined statically at compile-time***. And so this means you ***cannot change the implementations inherited from parent classes at run-time***.

1. While I understand run-time vs. compile time, I couldn't quite understand it in terms of defining class inheritance as per above.
   Does the above statement mean that when intermediate code is run to convert high-level code to machine code- this is when class inheritance is 'defined'? - And by defined we mean the connection is established between the parent and child class?
2. My understanding of run-time is the time it takes to execute one's code. How would we ever be able to change the implementations inherited  from parent classes at run-time? I must be understanding part of this incorrectly.

Any examples would be great if applicable.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC then this example clearly illustrates that changing parent implementations at run-time is possible both by changing parent's method and by changing child's method, in both cases dynamically:

```py
class Parent:

    @staticmethod
    def method():
        print("hey")


class Child(Parent):
    pass


Child.method()

Parent.method = lambda: print("hello")
Child.method()

Parent.method = lambda: print("hey")
Child.method = lambda: print("hello")
Child.method()
```

Output:

```
hey
hello
hello
```